# How can I customize Reformat Code in PhpStorm to add return value types for functions?

Tags: phpstorm

I click on the top menu "Code -> Reformat Code". The code is formatted, but return value types for functions not added. How to configure it? I can't find this checkbox.

[image]

Comment: There is no such code style setting as this is actually a quick-fix, not a formatter feature.

Comment: @duck_in_hat maybe there is some kind of plugin?